# How to calculate temperature of an incandescent bulb filament?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature

Suppose we have a light bulb, for which we know its power rating, like voltage of $12\mathrm V$, and power consumption of $10\mathrm W$. We also know it's a halogen bulb with a tungsten filament inside. Suppose we also know temperature of the surrounding air.

Is this data enough to compute temperature of the filament? If not, what should also be included? And anyway, how do we find the temperature?

Comment: No it is not enough to assume or even calculate the temperature which is independent of the watt or voltage ratingYou must expect a hot tungsten halogen light to be at least 4000'K while standard tungsten light is below 3000'K depending on design for lifespan. usually 2800 'K

Comment: It is dependent on the watts per certain length knowing the cooling rate in argon and the thermal resistance of the filament to reach an equilibrium temperature rise above ambient.  The designer chooses a tradeoff between brightness and lifespan with the colour temperature and ambient lack of convection air flow in enclosed luminaires has a serious detrimental effects on lifespan. from Arrhenius Law..   So if it is not at least 4000 to 5000'K it is not natural white and thus both answers are nice but wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really are asking two questions.

**First** - how do we calculate the temperature:

At the typical temperatures of an incandescent bulb, the large majority of heat loss is due to thermal radiation. Because of this, the most important factor is the "apparent size" of the filament. I say "apparent" because when you have a tightly wound coil, the parts of the coil facing other parts of the coil don't contribute to a net heat loss - they receive as much heat as they emit.

If you took for example a 5 mm long, tightly wound filament with a mean diameter (after winding) of 0.5 mm, you would have a surface area of approximately $5·π·0.5 \sim 8 \textrm{ mm}^2$. If you had 10 W of emission, you would use the Stefan Boltzmann law to get the power per unit area:

$$I = \sigma T^4$$

from which we get a temperature of

$$T = \sqrt[4]{\frac{10}{8\cdot 10^{-6}\cdot5.67\cdot 10^{-8}}} \approx 2100 K$$

This is of course for illustration only - at 2100 K the bulb is not very bright. Specifically, a real filament has emissivity less than 1.0 which would mean it would run a little hotter (though that pesky 4th power limits the impact somewhat).

Getting more accurate numbers is quite hard - there are lots of subtle effects (conduction down the support wires, heat lost due to imperfect vacuum, emissivity, and "true effective area" to name just four).

**Second** - how do we measure the temperature. For such high temperatures, the [disappearing filament pyrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappearing-filament_pyrometer) is very effective: you send a current through a calibrated filament, and compare its color against the color of the object of interest. When the filament "disappears" against the background, the temperatures are matched. Often, filters are used to do the comparison in a narrower range of wavelengths; the result can give resolution down to 10C according to the above linked article. There are obvious problems with this if the emissivity of the object of interest is (very) different than that of the filament - but if you are trying to determine the temperature of a filament, using a filament, that is not likely to be a problem.

Comment: the surface of a cylinder is 2πrh not πrh, in addition, you need to multiply the term of emissivity of a
body, for tungsten is 0.3

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro I did say “ diameter” not “radius”... fair point about emissivity. Note that by the time you take the fourth root, 0.3^(0.25)=0.74 so the effect is not huge ( but also not insignificant)

Comment: That's nice, but it disagrees with my tungsten experiment 10W @ 12V 14.42 ohms 2897 'K  warm white not YELLOW @ 2100 'K  Why would you assume they made any Halogen bulb other than bright white  > 4000 'K ?  If the theory doesn't match reality, change your theory.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the temperature and wattage are only loosely related - unless you know the effective area of the filament, you can’t deduce one from the other. With that said, tungsten halogen filaments typically can run hotter because the halogen helps preserve filament life (prevents tungsten from depositing on the bulb). Note the question was about “incandescent” not “tungsten halogen”…

Comment: OK but incandescent are usually 2800 to 2900 'K  (by design at nominal V) unless the "long life types" which use less power. I was misled by your reference to Halogen. this varies -300/+400 'K with +/-10% Vac

Comment: My “example filament” just used some round numbers, not actual values for actual filaments. To get to sufficiently high filament temperatures at low power, you really need a very small area (or lower emissivity ). I am not disputing your figures - but they don’t undermine the calculation unless you have the actual dimensions of the filament.

Comment: @Floris my experiments disagree with your statement about P vs T "being loosely related"  regardless if one knows the physical dimensions.  A  100 W bulb operated at 2890 'K and the temperature rate  was linear with power +/-20%.  That tells me that the thermal resistance Rja, from filament junction to ambient was constant.  'K/watt and the Tempco  was linear = 26.16 * [W] + 282 'K.  FWIW  convection air velocity affects Rja  (anecdotal info)

Comment: I guess this means tungsten filaments are NOT black bodies. @Floris so the analysis is not accurate.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - the nice thing about the "disappearing filament" approach is that as long as the filament has similar properties to the body of interest, it doesn't matter that they are not "black" bodies. All the calculations I showed are "for illustration only" with the expectation that an intelligent user will modify them to fit their specific instance. I modified language in the question to make this more clear.

Comment: that's better for inexperienced users  but halogen still needs higher temps otherwise the recombinant recycling savings are lost.   So you ought to have said an ordinary argon/helium tungsten bulb or a quartz argon tungsten heater..The "not black body " implication in my statement means the not quite accurate formula as the thermal resistance of the surface and enclosure has a big effect on the filament temp.

Comment: (which in turn has a huge impact on MTBF from Arrhenius Effect)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 OK OK I removed the reference to halogen.

Comment: Very good, but I wonder how thermodynamics come to play in blackbody temps with thermal conductance/resistance.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The filament will be a reasonable approximation to a [black body emitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body), so it's spectrum will be given by [Planck's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law):

$$ B = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{hc}{k\lambda T}} - 1} $$

So just measure the radiance of the light from the filament for a range of wavelengths and do a fit to Planck's law by varying $T$. This will give you an excellent approximation to the temperature.

Comment: There is a wonderful instrument called a "[disappearing filament bolometer (or pyrometer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappearing-filament_pyrometer)" that superposes the image of a (calibrated) glowing filament over the image of a hot surface. You adjust the current through the filament until it "disappears" against the background (the color matches). That is in essence what this method does.

Comment: Too bad this formula is what I was going to use to calibrate spectral response of my spectrometer. So for me, this answer appears circular :)

Comment: @Ruslan - it sounds to me like you actually intended to ask a different question than the one you posed, then?

Comment: @Floris well, if I asked the whole question about calibration, this would be "too many questions in one", so I just asked what I thought to be first. I was wondering about this particular question I actually asked for a long time though, so it's also interesting on its own.